# Output image data using PIL pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Can someone explain to me why are these two codes produce two different outputs.

a.

```
import urllib
txt = urllib.urlopen("image.jpeg").read()
print(txt)
```

b.

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import io

img = Image.open('image.jpeg')
#img.save("./test.jpeg", "JPEG")# <- this saves a correct file
with io.BytesIO() as output:
  img.save(output, format="JPEG")
  contents = output.getvalue()
  print(contents)# <- this prints something totally different ???
```

Comment: Different programs/libraries may compress JPEG images slightly differently. Moreover JPEG is a "lossy" format so image details may be lost on (re)compression.

Comment: If i do 'img.save("./test.jpeg", "JPEG")" and then do md5sum on it - it'll be the same as the original image.jpeg. But if I run the script and redirect the output to a file the md5sum of that file is different. It looks like ".save()" and .getvalue() produce different results.

Comment: On ***a.***, you have to do `img = base64.encodestring(txt)`

Comment: a. prints the correct blob, b. does not.

Comment: Python 2? Surely not - it's finished in a few weeks and Python3 has been out for 10 years!

Comment: using Python 3.7